# why inheritance is strongly coupled where as composition is loosely coupled in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, composition

I have heard this `favor composition over inheritance` again and again in design patterns. some of the reasons cited for this are

```
1)Inheritance is strongly coupled where as composition is loosely coupled
2) Inheritance is compile time determined where as composition is run-time
3)Inheritance breaks encapsulation where as composition does not
4) anything else I am not aware of
```

It would be great for beginners like to me follow these by illustrations as how inheritance and composition differs with respect to above points. I have read various SO links that talks about them, but walk through examples on these key points would be great for Java beginners.

I think it is very crucial to understand the difference clearly than just memorizing the points.

Comment: Several of the numbered items above would benefit from including the phrase "may" or "may be".

Comment: [This nice article](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html) will answer the question gracefully.

Answer (score 10):

Nice question and big for a beginner, I think I should first remind the reader what inheritance and composition are, and then go on to explain what exactly `Favor Composition over Inheritance` means.
**Pros and Cons of Inheritance** :

**Advantages:**

- One of the prime benefits of dynamic binding and polymorphism is that
  they can help make code easier to change.
- New implementation is easy, since most of it is inherited. It's easy to
  modify or extend the implementation being reused.

**Disadvantages:**

- Breaks encapsulation, since it exposes a subclass to implementation
  details of its super-class.
- `White-box` reuse, since internal details of super-classes are often
  visible to subclasses.
- Subclasses may have to be changed if the implementation of the
  superclass changes. Implementations inherited from superclasses can
  not be changed at runtime.

About the question:

> Inheritance is strongly coupled where as composition is loosely coupled

Inheritance will bring you tight coupling, simply one change to base class can break many child classes.
**But when to use and how detect we need inheritance or composition?**
Use inheritance only when all of the following criteria are satisfied (Coad's Rule):

1. A subclass expresses `is a special kind of` and not `is a role played by a`.
2. An instance of a subclass never needs to become an object of another class.
3. A subclass extends, rather than overrides or nullifies, the responsibilities of 
   its super-class.
4. A subclass does not extend the capabilities of what is merely a
   utility class.
5. For a class in the actual Problem Domain, the subclass specializes
           a role, transaction or device.

> Inheritance is compile time determined where as composition is run-time

When compiled, your base class codes will be added to every child class.

> Inheritance breaks encapsulation where as composition does not

Yes. Now you see the disadvantage of inheritance.

**The bottom line is**:

**Make sure inheritance models the is-a relationship**
My main guiding philosophy is that inheritance should be used only when a subclass *is-a* superclass. In the example above, an `Apple` likely is-a `Fruit`, so I would be inclined to use inheritance.

An important question to ask yourself when you think you have an is-a relationship is whether that is-a relationship will be constant throughout the lifetime of the application and, with luck, the lifecycle of the code. For example, you might think that an `Employee` is-a `Person`, when really `Employee` represents a role that a `Person` plays part of the time. What if the person becomes unemployed? What if the person is both an `Employee` and a `Supervisor`? Such impermanent is-a relationships should usually be modelled with composition.

**Don't use inheritance just to get code reuse**
  If all you really want is to reuse code and there is no is-a relationship in sight, use composition.

**Don't use inheritance just to get at polymorphism**
  If all you really want is polymorphism, but there is no natural is-a relationship, use composition with interfaces.
**Favor composition Over Inheritance :)**

I took it straight from the [javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html?page=3).

Comment: looks like you copied and pasted from http://www.javaworld.com/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html?page=3.

Comment: its a general question and i try to explain step by step.i try to help you. yes some part of answer is just copy and past.

Comment: In my personal experience, having to deal with legacy Enterprise source code, that used inheritance fanatically for code reuse, I was blocked in [Yo-yo problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem), [unit test was nearly impossible](http://craigpardey.com/wp/2012/07/anti-pattern-re-use-through-inheritance/), inheritance cased [Rigidity](http://www.ifi.uzh.ch/seal/teaching/courses/archive/hs11/reeng/04-OODesignPrinciplesAndViolations.pdf), violating LSP is a known [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)

Comment: The idea of "Is A" is nonsensical in my opinion.

If an Apple was a Fruit that does not change any behavior, you wouldn't create a sub-class.

Therefor an Apple would be as much of a role as an Employee.

This is why inheritance just doesn't really make sense to me, other than ensuring Interfaces are kept.

An Apple can be treated like a Fruit, just like an Employee can be treated like a Person.

At this point never assuming "Is A" seems like the only sane assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance is expressed in code using extends for concrete classes.  Once you write it, you can't change it without rewriting the classes.  I can only change by modifying code.

```
public class Foo {
    public void doSomething() { System.out.println("I'm a Foo"); }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    public void doSomething() { super.doSomething(); }
}
```

I can only change what `Bar` does by modifying one or both classes.

Composition is usually interface-based, which means that you specify what is done, not how.  You can change the how without affecting clients simply by changing the implementation of the interface.

```
public interface Foo {
    void doSomething();
}

public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    public void doSomething() { System.out.println("I'm a Foo"); }
}

public class Bar implements Foo {
    private Foo foo;

    public Bar(Foo f) { this.foo = f; }

    public void doSomething() { this.foo.doSomething(); }
}
```

I can change the behavior of `Bar` in this case simply by passing a different implementation of the `Foo` interface.

It's one of Bob Martin's [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) principles: [The Open/Closed Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/ocp.pdf).

Comment: even with interface,the class that implements the interface, has to implement the methods of the interface, which involves rewriting of the implementations in the implementing class..?

Comment: Does composition *have* to use an interface?  Can't you use a concrete `class`?

Comment: Interface based is best, IMO.

Comment: IMO you should put a comment about delegation.

Comment: OP, you are going to have to change code unless you design a composition framework. In that case, the composition of an object would be completely data based, but you'd be constrained to the framework you are using / wrote.

Comment: Thanks for the example. can you tell me why inheritance breaks encapsulation whereas composition in this example?